# How to add points using User Points in Drupal 6

Tags: 7, theming, rating, userpoints

I want users to be able to give points to other users through "User Points"

I think it's the API: http://drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions!userpoints!userpoints.module/6
http://drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions!userpoints!userpoints.views.inc/6

I don't want to use views module, I'm looking for a PHP code to place it in template and to give point.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check [nodevote](http://drupal.org/project/nodevote) module. It does something similar. You may use it directly or base your code on it.

If you want to use a more sofisticated solution with VotingAPI you can use  [userpoints_votingapi](http://drupal.org/project/userpoints_votingapi) and use rate module for the widgets

Cheers.